# State is updating to the component but props is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I just tried to integrate redux into my react-native application.CombineReducer used to combine two reducers but it gives me undefined props.

**CounterComponent**

```
 function mapStateToProps(state) {
   console.log(props)  //undefined
   console.log(state); // counterReducer: { counter: 2 }
   return {
       counter: state.counter
   };
  }
```

**reducerIndex.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { todoReducer } from './todoReducer';
import { counterReducer } from './counterReducer';
export default combineReducers({
  counterReducer,
  todoReducer
});
```

**App.js**

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <Provider store={store}>
       <CounterApp />
      </Provider>
   );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah it should give you undefined because inside of mapStateToProps doesn’t know what does props means. Only state being passed inside the function. You can still use props inside your class and get redux store values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah thats a valid `undefined` for the props being accessed in the `mapStateToProps` because the `mapStateToProps` is just a normal function that exposes the redux state to your component that you have attached to the store using `connect`. `mapStateToProps` doesn't know your component props but **it does update them or add more to it by giving your redux state to your component as props** thats why it is a good convention to write the function name as `mapStateToProps` !
so when you write the following:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super (props);
   }
   ......
   .....
   render () {
    return <MyCoolComponent />
   }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {myreducer} = state;
  return {
     data: myreducer.data 
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch, ownProps) {
   return {
      updateData: () => {
         dispatch(someAction());  //someAction: this will return something like this: {type: MY_UPDATE_ACTION}
      }
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyContainer);
```

So in the `MyContainer` component, you will have the access to the `data` as one of its props. You can access data anywhere in the class using `this.props.data`.

On the other hand `mapDispatchToProps` exposes functions as props to the attached component, the functions being exposed have access to the `dispatch` which actually dispatches an action to the store thereby giving power to your component to mutate the redux store. So with the above explanation, `updateData` function can be accessed from anywhere in the `MyContainer` using `this.props.updateData()`.